# When the "native pixel object" will be still in use at the native level in the method nativeRecycle()?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have checked the source code of the method `recycle()` of **Bitmap** in android-21 , and I saw this:

```
public void recycle() {
  if (!mRecycled) {
    if (nativeRecycle(mNativeBitmap)) {
       // return value indicates whether native pixel object was actually recycled.
       // false indicates that it is still in use at the native level and these
       // objects should not be collected now. They will be collected later when the
       // Bitmap itself is collected.
       mBuffer = null;
       mNinePatchChunk = null;
    }
    mRecycled = true;
  }
}
```

I was confused about the comment **false indicates that it is still in use at the native level**, when the native pixel object will still be use at the native level?
If the method `nativeRecycle(mNativeBitmap)` return false, does it mean that the related memory should then only be collected by the GC? Because when you first call the `recycle() method`, the `mRecycled` will be set to true, and you can never go to the method `nativeRecycle(mNativeBitmap)` again.

Answer (score 1):

See Bitmap.cpp source.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp

```
static const JNINativeMethod gBitmapMethods[] = {
    ...
    { "nativeRecycle", "(J)Z", (void*)Bitmap_recycle },
    ...
}
```

nativeRecycle() calls Bitmap_recycle().

```
static jboolean Bitmap_recycle(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jlong bitmapHandle) {
    LocalScopedBitmap bitmap(bitmapHandle);
    bitmap->freePixels();
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

bitmap->freePixels() calls

```
void Bitmap::freePixels() {
    AutoMutex _lock(mLock);
    if (mPinnedRefCount == 0) {
        doFreePixels();
        mPixelStorageType = PixelStorageType::Invalid;
    }
}
```

This means if a bitmap is used more than once and some of them are not freed yet (reference count is left), the bitmap is treated as still in use.

(But Bitmap_recycle() seems to return true...)

---

recycle() is for Java object (A).
nativeRecycle() is NOT for Java object (B).

A:B is many:1 reference.
So, even if one of A is recycled, B can be alive.
And recycle() of another A is called, nativeRecycle() of B is called.

GC is for Java object (A).
Not for native one (B).

Comment: So, Does it mean if we call the method recycle() and the bitmap still have other references the system will handle it to the GC? Because the  mRecycled field will be set to true, and nativeRecycle() will never be called again.

Comment: Added explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanations, it is helpful for me to understand this source code snippet, by the way, how I can gain these related knowledge? Or, where can I find about it?

Comment: @zhenganyi These knowledge are part of  Android NDK (Native Development Kit) and JNI (Java Native Interface), but it's a little hard to read. So, search with "msdn marshalling" may be good to get the concept. (Marshalling is for passing values between C# and C/C++(native). C# uses GC and C++ doesn't. Managed heap is for C#, unmanaged heap is for C/C++.) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(v=vs.110).aspx And another choice. Search with "JNI marshalling".